Would the poulterer's be open on Christmas Day for Scrooge to buy their prize turkey?
The last chapter of Dickens' A Christmas Carol famously starts off with Scrooge asking a boy on the street what day it is. After rejoicing that it is still Christmas Day, he sends the boy off to the Poulterer's ("in the next street but one, at the corner") to buy the big prize turkey that has been hanging there, and then has it delivered (via cab) to Bob Cratchit.
I know Christmas wasn't universally celebrated in 19th century America, but this is in England. Wouldn't stores be closed on Christmas Day? Would the poultry shop even be open, never mind have a man available to deliver prize turkeys to Camden Town?
(I was also wondering what poor Mrs. Cratchit would do with a gigantic turkey in her entirely oven-free four-room dwelling, but I guess she'd send it to the baker?)

"but I guess she'd send it to the baker", which means that the bakery was open for business.  So... why not the Poulterer?

Delivery was to be by cab, so the shop was not involved in delivery..

@RonJohn: the baker's oven was used by pretty much everyone who needed to do any baking, because houses did not have ovens. That doesn't mean the bakery was necessarily open.

@RussellMcMahon, the text mentions the poulterer's man taking the turkey where it needed to go. Cabs transport people - they'll take stuff if it comes with the people, but they're not a package delivery service.

@Martha "That doesn't mean the bakery was necessarily open."  The bakery was private property, not a Commons.  Thus, since the baker had to pay rent no matter what, I'm really darned dubious about your assertion that he'd just let people use his bakery and fuel for free.

Where did I say or imply that any of this was for free?

@Martha even if it's "we'll pay you later", bakeries are not Commons; the baker's going to be there to do the baking for them, schedule access, etc.  Why not let people do it themselves?  Are you going to let unsupervised strangers play with fire on your property, or will you be there to make sure the fires don't go out, the fires don't burn too hot, food doesn't burn, get stolen, etc?

My local butchers is open on Xmas Day, to allow people to collect their turkeys and prepared meats. I assume that the same would be true in a London where people don't typically have a fridge freezer or an oven

Please don't discuss in comments; update the question to address the issue, then flag the comment for deletion. OP should very rarely comment.

@mARTHA You are correct! (You know that :-) ) . Maybe making the process clearer in the question would be useful to others than just me :-). Maybe not. || I like the Hookey Walker reference :-) . ||"It's hanging there now," replied the boy.
"Is it?" said Scrooge. "Go and buy it." "Walk-ER!" exclaimed the boy.
"No, no," said Scrooge, "I am in earnest. Go and buy it, and tell 'em to bring it here, that I may give them the directions where to take it. Come back with the man, and I'll give you a shilling. Come back with him in less than five minutes, and I'll give you half-a-crown!"

text || Dickens original !!! here - I imagine that as the Poulterer's is "in the next street but one, at the corner" and that the TT size Turkey is still unsold ON Christmas day may make the shopkeeper happy enough to deliver it two blocks. (One would so hope, anyway).

@RussellMcMahon - It's a sign of the influence of scrooge-like figures (like Scrooge) that nobody in the area was wealthy enough to buy the big turkey.

@Richard That comment is ambiguous. It's unclear whether it is a complaint re socio-economic inequity, or ... ? Otherwise: Poulterers et al usually acquire stock with an eye to possible profit best case and losses worst case. It seems highly likely that they expect that there is a good possibility that SOMEONE will buy their utterly immense turkey. In this instance, they were right. So stocking an expensive turkey that someone will probably buy probably counts, as you say, as the influence of there being people who will probably buy an expensive turkey.

@RussellMcMahon - It's not that big a risk. If nobody buys it at Xmas, they might buy it a few days later at a discount, or it can just be jointed up and sold as parts. The fact that everyone has seen it locally means that it might just have been used as an advert, effectively.

@RussellMcMahon - I do quite like the contemporary criticism that Scrooge's largesse has resulted in an orphange or public event going without the gigantic turkey that the poulterer was saving for them.

@Richard :-) . I'd never heard that suggestion. Makes some sense.  || I was looking at very large "Christmas hams" in the local supermarket tonight. Reduced as Christmas approached, more reduced now, stay tuned ... .

Almost ten years ago the Law Bod Blog, the blog of the Bodleian Libraries at the University of Oxford, wrote about this topic:

But what would the law have been on the morning in Victorian England when Scrooge leant out of his window?  A Christmas Carol was published in 1843, and that year Christmas fell on a Monday.  The Chronological Table and Index of the Statutes (for these purposes, the 15th edition which covers statutes between 1235 and 1899) provides a useful index of legislation in force, while Justis will provide the full text online.  The 19th century saw a flurry of Sunday observance legislation limiting public entertainment, drinking, work, sport, railway travel and more, leading one commentator to describe the Victorian Sunday as “the last word in dullness”.  Although established under common law as a public holiday in England, Christmas Day does not seem to have been explicitly subject to all the same restrictions.  The index shows that by the mid-1800’s, pawnbrokers, public houses, and billiards houses were all forbidden from opening on Christmas Day, but not shops.

The paragraph in the original contains links to the respective sources, which I didn't rebuild here.
So while there were some regulations prohibiting opening a business on Sundays, these regulations didn't all necessarily apply to Christmas day (unless Christmas day happened to fall on a Sunday, of course). There were some business that were forbidden from opening on Christmas day, but shops were not among them. So it would have been up to individual shop owner whether to open the store or not.
There's no overarching regulation to this day (or at least in 2015), by the way, as the same article as above mentions:

These days he certainly wouldn’t be able to pop out to a nearby superstore, as opening hours of large stores in England are governed by the Christmas Day (Trading) Act 2004.  This states, “A large shop must not be open on Christmas Day for the serving of retail customers”, where large means any shop with over 280 square metres of floor space.  Smaller shops are not subject to this legislation, so today Scrooge might still be able to find the makings of a festive bacon sandwich at his local corner shop.  (And so a small butcher’s shop could theoretically be open on Christmas morning.)


I believe many shop owners lived at/above their shop at the time, so getting hold of them to "open" the shop when they were at home chilling with their family wouldn't have been overly difficult. Particularly if you had lots of money you were anxious to spend.

Interestingly the means there is nothing forcing Scrooge to give Cratchitt the day off.

@DJClayworth Yeah, the argument wasn’t “it’s the law,” it was “everyone you would do business with is closed, so you won’t be able to do anything useful anyway.”

@DJClayworth It probably depends at least partially on what Scrooge's business actually is. AFAIR that's not spelled out in the book, but most sources I can find interpret Scrooge as an accountant, commodity trader, money lender or giving out something like payday loans. My answer focuses on stores. As the first quote says, at least pawn brokers were prohibited from opening on Christmas day.

I don't think there's any law in the US requiring businesses to be closed on Xmas, but in my experience the only places that are open are movie theatres and Chinese restaurants. The latter tend to be full of Jews.

Maybe some supermarkets are open for shorter hours than usual.

In the United Kingdom, even within my own lifetime, there has been a progressive trend towards "everything stops for Xmas Day, except the TV adverts". When I was a lad, a card posted on Christmas Eve (before putting up the decorations) arrived first thing on Christmas Day...

@Barmar Yes, movie theaters are open. I worked at one as a teenager, and I worked on all the holidays.Chinese restaurants are open, usually. Convenience stores may be open. A skating rink may be open. And they are all filled with Jews, I'm sure... pu-leeze

@MarkMorganLloyd  I remember that as recently as the 1980s, the men of our extended family would go to the pub on Christmas day to let the women get on with the cooking. And of course there would be plenty of Indian/Pakistani-owned corner shops open.

There's no refrigeration in this time period.  Of necessity, birds and other animals would be slaughtered and cooked almost immediately.  So the shops selling the best live animals for would certainly have been open for Christmas.  It might be their most important day of the year.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

"There's no refrigeration in this time period." seems a little too affirmative. Louis XIV intendants/stewards had (in many places/castles) six+ meters deep holes, with ice at the bottom, so that they could keep food cold. At this depth, cold is already good enough for keeping food. In many medieval cities, there were galleries deep under the houses, where wealthy people would keep their goods/food locked, at a very low temperature (see Provins, for instance, a place I visited and studied).

FWIW: London is in the depths of winter at Christmas. The movie (my only exposure to the story) depicts the streets full of snow. Refrigeration would likely not be an issue in this situation. This would, of course, depend on the weather for the particular year. Happy New Year! :-)

An interesting article at the LOC talks about the turkeys being raised and slaughtered in Norfolk, then transported via coach and later, by Dickens time, by rail to the market areas. Modern thought puts too much emphasis on the need for refrigeration.

This prize turkey has already been killed, it is hanging in the window, unsold, inside.  It is not in some ice room, but on display.  It's early enough on Christmas for the poulterer to be open for business, selling what's the already been killed for Christmas dinners and close early.  The question is more about commerce than livestock/food handling.  Merry Christmas.

The book earlier describes the poulterers as being "half open" as a lot of their stock would already be sold.

@patsw - It's freezing cold outside and the turkey was likely kept in the window where it would also be freezing. The implication is that it's the market poulterer at Leadenhall; https://www.london-walking-tours.co.uk/dickens-london/dickens-images/leadenhall-market-christmas-eve-lady-20-12-1856.jpg. as you can see, the turkeys were hung outside to the elements.

I believe it was common to hang game birds for around ten days to improve the flavour, not sure if that applied to domesticated fowl.  Oh, BTW @Fe2O3, winter has barely got going in London in December, the coldest time is probably sometime in February.  The Hollywood myth of a white Christmas in England is far from the truth.
